# How to stop a for loop and program if malloc returns nothing back

Tags: c, malloc

So I have this for loop where I allocate memory for each string in pointers array

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(14 * sizeof(char));
}
```

If I check for the value of the `malloc` return in the `for` loop itself, my school compiler gives me some errors

```
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = malloc(14 * sizeof(char));
        if (!ptr[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
            exit(-10);
        } 
    }
```

How can I properly check if `malloc` returns a value and memory is actually allocated, in `for` loop?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N  2

int main(void) {
    char **ptr;
    ptr = (char **)malloc(N * (sizeof(char *)));
    if (!ptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
        exit(-10);
    }
    char *hamburger = "hamburger";
    char *icecream = "icecream";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        if (!ptr[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
            exit(-10);
        }
    }

    strcpy(ptr[0], hamburger);
    strcpy(ptr[1], icecream);
    char *end = "pay";
    char input[80] = "";
    int price = 0;
    while (!str_compare(input, end)) {
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (str_compare(ptr[0], input))
            price += 150;
        if (str_compare(ptr[1], input))
            price += 40;
    }
    printf("Total price %d", price);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(ptr[i]);
    }

    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
    hamburger = NULL;
    icecream = NULL;
 
    end = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

The error :D

> > =================================================================
> > ==13==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000000dd at pc 0x5637075280da bp 0x7ffc25536920 sp
> > 0x7ffc255360c8 WRITE of size 14 at 0x6020000000dd thread T0
> > #0 0x5637075280d9 in __interceptor_strcpy.part.0 (/work/main+0x380d9)
> > #1 0x5637075c8836 in main FINAL-FASTFOOD.c:69
> > #2 0x7fc505e0bcb1 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x28cb1)
> > #3 0x5637074f843d in _start (/work/main+0x843d)
>
> 0x6020000000dd is located 0 bytes to the right of 13-byte region
> [0x6020000000d0,0x6020000000dd) allocated by thread T0 here:
> #0 0x563707584d77 in malloc (/work/main+0x94d77)
> #1 0x5637075c85a7 in main FINAL-FASTFOOD.c:53
> #2 0x7fc505e0bcb1 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x28cb1)
>
> SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/work/main+0x380d9)
> in __interceptor_strcpy.part.0 Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
> 0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 05 fa fa 00 05 fa fa 00 05 fa fa 00 05
> =>0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 05 fa fa 00 05 fa fa 00[05]fa fa fa fa   0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa Shadow
> byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
> Addressable:           00   Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06
> 07    Heap left redzone:       fa   Freed heap region:       fd
> Stack left redzone:      f1   Stack mid redzone:       f2   Stack
> right redzone:     f3   Stack after return:      f5   Stack use after
> scope:   f8   Global redzone:          f9   Global init order:
> f6   Poisoned by user:        f7   Container overflow:      fc   Array
> cookie:            ac   Intra object redzone:    bb   ASan internal:
> fe   Left alloca redzone:     ca   Right alloca redzone:    cb
> Shadow gap:              cc
> ==13==ABORTING

Comment: The code is incomplete. We cannot confirm what `ptr` is, or `N`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: i edited the question with whole code

Comment: N is 2, so `ptr[2]` through `ptr[6]` are out of bounds.

Comment: Where is the `str_compare` function? Are you still getting the error even after you removed the out of bounds access? Is it the same error? The reason I doubt is that the line numbers in the error originally posted don't match up with any of the versions of code you've posted. Admittedly, sometimes they are wrong, but it is suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question is inconsistent with the code in the program: you use a length of 14 bytes vs: 10 bytes in the program... Are you sure the error occurs for the posted code?

The allocation performed seems correct, but the comparison loop is incorrect as you compare the input **before** actually reading it.  Furthermore you do not tell `scanf()` the maximum number of bytes to store into `input`, which can cause undefined behavior for long input words: this is a typical flaw attackers could use to try and execute arbitrary code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N  2

bool str_compare(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    return !strcmp(s1, s2);
}

int main(void) {
    char **ptr;
    ptr = malloc(N * (sizeof(char *)));
    if (!ptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
        exit(-10);
    }
    const char *hamburger = "hamburger";
    const char *icecream = "icecream";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        ptr[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        if (!ptr[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
            exit(-10);
        }
    }

    strcpy(ptr[0], hamburger);
    strcpy(ptr[1], icecream);

    const char *end = "pay";
    char input[80];
    int price = 0;
    while (scanf("%79s", input) == 1 && !str_compare(input, end)) {
        if (str_compare(ptr[0], input))
            price += 150;
        else
        if (str_compare(ptr[1], input))
            price += 40;
        else
            printf("unknown item: %s\n", input);
    }
    printf("Total price %d\n", price);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are allocating 2 * `char` Pointer, but the `for` Loop is allocating three times.  The last time, when memory is allocated ah buffer overflows happen, because you did not allocate 3 * `char` Pointers

Try to change the `for` Loop like this:

```
For(int i=0; i <= N; i++)
```

Comment: The code you've proposed would cause the loop to iterate 3 times and write past the end of the allocated pointers. It adds to any other problems in the original code.